# How to put multiple fonts in a widget

Tags: python, user-interface, text, fonts, tkinter

How would I be able to multiple fonts into a widget?

I found out this may work.

```
b=Button(frame, text="Big bold text\n" "Small text")
```

I have tried many things however i can't get my code to work.
Simply put, I want a big bold text and a small text underneath each other.

Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: I don't believe the standard button widget supports that. You'd need to create your own button widget.

Comment: `Button` can't do this. You can create own widget using `Frame` and many `Label`s with different fonts.

Comment: _"I found out this may work."_ - where did you find that out? That definitely won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the Tk button widget nor the ttk button widget support the use of multiple fonts for the text element. However, you can construct something using the Canvas widget to get two separate text elements within a single widget. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38014382/291641) about making vertical text buttons provides a similar example that would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this thread is quite old at the time of writing but wanted this exact problem but with a `Label` instead. To solve this, please try the following code (hopefully it is very self-explanatory to use):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import *

def example_method (): print ("Click!")

class Button2:

    """
Allows multiple fonts in a very simple button.
Only supports 'master', 'text' and 'command' keywords
    ('master' is compulsory)
Fonts are delared in < > with the following options:
    BOLD = Make the text bold
    ITALIC = Make the text italic
    STRIKEOUT = Strike through the text
    UNDERLINE = Underlines the text
    an integer = the text size
    any other keyword is assumed to be the text family
    For the default text style, leave the < > empty
NOTE: Only supports the grid method due to internal handelling
    """

    def __init__ (self, master, text = "<>", command = None):

        self.f, self.command = Frame (root, relief = RAISED, borderwidth = 3), command
        self.f.bind ("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.__click ())
        self.f.bind ("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: self.__release ())

        sections = [i.split (">") for i in text.split ("<") [1 : ]]

        row, column = 0, 0
        for section in sections:

            font_decomp, kw = section [0].split ("_"), {}
            for keyword in font_decomp:
                if keyword == "STRIKEOUT": kw ["overstrike"] = True
                elif keyword == "BOLD": kw ["weight"] = BOLD
                elif keyword == "ITALIC": kw ["slant"] = ITALIC
                elif keyword == "UNDERLINE": kw ["underline"] = True
                try: kw ["size"] = int (keyword)
                except: kw ["family"] = keyword

            temp_font = Font (**kw)
            l = Label (self.f, text = section [1].replace ("\n", ""), font = temp_font)
            l.grid (row = row, column = column)
            l.bind ("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.__click ())
            l.bind ("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: self.__release ())

            if section [1].count ("\n") >= 1:
                column = -1
                for i in range (section [1].count ("\n") - 1):
                    l = Label (self.f, text = "", font = temp_font)
                    l.grid (row = row, column = column)
                    l.bind ("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.__click ())
                    l.bind ("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: self.__release ())
                    row += 1
                row += 1
            column += 1

    def __click (self):
        self.f.config (relief = SUNKEN)
        if self.command: self.command ()

    def __release (self): self.f.config (relief = RAISED)

    def grid (self, **kw): self.f.grid (**kw)

root = Tk ()
root.title ("Multiple fonts")
Button2 (root, text = "<30_BOLD>Big bold text\n<10>Small text", command = example_method).grid ()
root.mainloop ()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use many font sizes and colors in a tkinter label, you should use a Text widget instead of an ordinary label. I have created fake widgets like fake label and fake button and it works perfectly. The fake label is IMO much better than an ordinary label because the text inside can be marked and copied to windows' clipboard with the mouse.
Below my code for fake button and fake label:

```
    import tkinter as tk

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300")

    # a Text widget looking and working like a button widget in Tkinter 
    fake_button1=tk.Text(root)
    fake_button1.place(x=50,y=100,width=200,height=40)

    # the text in the fake button can be adjusted with padx and pady ( 
    #like in CSS HTML) to place the text in the center ,-justify and 
    #anchor don't work 
    fake_button1.configure(padx="45", pady="10",font=("Arial Bold",12),bg="yellow")
    added_text_to_button=" PRINT HELLO"
    fake_button1.insert("end",added_text_to_button)
    #here configuration of letter colors - > from 6 the letter in the 
    #string ( Text is counting from 1 not from 0 !) to the 12th letter 
    #in the string
    fake_button1.tag_config("start", foreground="green")
    fake_button1.tag_add("start", "1.6", "1.12")
    #looks like a button - relief raised, cursor inside is an arrow
    fake_button1.configure(relief="raised",state="disabled", cursor="arrow")

    # after clicking the fake button function is launched
    def print_hello(event):
    #important - the text widget ( a fake button widget ) is sunken like 
    #a button after been clicked
        fake_button1.configure(relief="sunken")
        print("Hello")

    fake_button1.bind("<Button-1>",print_hello)

    #mouse left the button area
    #important -  after clicking the fake button widget must be raised 
    def relief_raised(event):
        fake_button1.configure(relief="raised")

    fake_button1.bind("<Leave>",relief_raised)


    fake_label1=tk.Text(root)
    fake_label1.place(x=50,y=200,width=200,height=45)

    
    fake_label1.configure( pady="10",font=("Arial Bold",12),bg="palegreen")

    added_text_to_label="I AM A FAKE LABEL"
    fake_label1.insert("end",added_text_to_label)

    fake_label1.configure(relief="flat",state="disabled", cursor="arrow")
    fake_label1.tag_config("start", foreground="red" , font=("Arial Bold",16) )
    fake_label1.tag_add("start", "1.7", "1.11")
```