# Creating actions for canvas Button with the effect on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm following [Is it possible to have a vertical-oriented button in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008389/is-it-possible-to-have-a-vertical-oriented-button-in-tkinter) and [How do you create a Button on a tkinter Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980812/how-do-you-create-a-button-on-a-tkinter-canvas) as the guideline to create some actions for Button on a Tkinter Canvas?. The actions worked, but the effect of `Button` is frozen.

The code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkfont
main = tk.Tk()
font = tkfont.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
label = "Click Me"
height = font.measure(label) + 4
width = font.metrics()['linespace'] + 4
canvas = tk.Canvas(main, height=height, width=width, background="SystemButtonFace", borderwidth=2, relief="raised")
canvas.create_text((4, 4), angle="90", anchor="ne", text=label, fill="SystemButtonText", font=font)

canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda ev: ev.widget.configure(relief="sunken"))
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda ev: ev.widget.configure(relief="raised"))
canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda ev: submit())

def submit():
    print("1")

canvas.place(x=5, y=height + 10)
main.mainloop()
```

If I remove `canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda ev: submit())`, then the effect of `Button` worked, but there is `Submit` action.

Otherwise, If leave the code like above which contains the line `canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda ev: submit())`, then the effect of `Button` is frozen, but the `Submit` action works.

I'm looking for a way to have either the effect of `Button` and `Submit`  action work together. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `add=True` on the second bind of `<ButtonPress-1>` event, so that the previous binding is not override:

```py
canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda ev: ev.widget.configure(relief="sunken"))
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda ev: ev.widget.configure(relief="raised"))
canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda ev: submit(), add=True) # added add=True
```